# Trying to marshal a csv string to a struct

Tags: csv, go

Here is my program :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/gocarina/gocsv"
)

// GeoAdresseCsv is a test structcd 
type GeoAdresseCsv struct {
    ID    int    `csv:"id"`
    IDBan string `csv:"id_ban"`
}

func main() {
    var adresseDB []GeoAdresseCsv
    stringCsv := `id;id_ban
    2908743;28009_0019_00008`

    err := gocsv.UnmarshalString(stringCsv, &adresseDB)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", adresseDB)
}
```

But the ouput that i get is :

> [{ID:0 IDBan:}]

How should i do correctly to get my csv string correctly mapped to my struct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the separator in your data is `;`, [the package](https://github.com/gocarina/gocsv) by default seems to use `,`.

So we need to configure the package to use a different separator. According to the documentation, this is possible with a [customizable CSV reader](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gocarina/gocsv#readme-customizable-csv-reader-writer):

```
gocsv.SetCSVReader(func(in io.Reader) gocsv.CSVReader {
    r := csv.NewReader(in)
    r.Comma = ';' // This is our separator now
    return r
})
```

This configures all functions in the package.

Your code should look like this to include the change:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"

    "github.com/gocarina/gocsv"
)

// GeoAdresseCsv is a test structcd
type GeoAdresseCsv struct {
    ID    int    `csv:"id"`
    IDBan string `csv:"id_ban"`
}

func main() {
    gocsv.SetCSVReader(func(in io.Reader) gocsv.CSVReader {
        r := csv.NewReader(in)
        r.Comma = ';' // This is our separator now
        return r
    })

    var adresseDB []GeoAdresseCsv
    stringCsv := `id;id_ban
    2908743;28009_0019_00008`

    err := gocsv.UnmarshalString(stringCsv, &adresseDB)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", adresseDB)
}
```

Now the output is the expected value:

```
[{ID:2908743 IDBan:28009_0019_00008}]
```

You can run it online [here](https://goplay.space/#uer2By-XbCV).